# read multiple file and compare with the fixed files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 50 files in a directory that are suppose to compare with one file, e.g., original.txt. I have the following code. It works well when I give the file name one-by-one, manually. I want to automate it for this  I used 'glob.blog'

```
folder = "files/"
path = '*.rbd'

path = folder + path
files=sorted(glob.glob(path))
```

Here the complete code:

```
import glob
from itertools import islice
import linecache

num_lines_nonbram =  1891427

bits_perline = 32

total_bit_flips =  0

num_bit_diff_flip_zero = 0
num_bit_diff_flip_ones = 0
folder = "files/"

path = '*.rbd'

path = folder + path
files=sorted(glob.glob(path))

original=open('files/mull-original-readback.rbd','r')


#source1 = open(file1, "r")



for filename in files:


 del_lines = 101

 with open(filename,'r') as f:

  i=1
  while i <= del_lines:
   line1 = f.readline()

   lineoriginal=original.readline()

   i+=1

  i=0  


  num_bit_diff_flip_zero = 0
  num_bit_diff_flip_ones = 0
  num_lines_diff =0

  i=0
  j=0
  k=0
  a_write2 = ""
  while i < (num_lines_nonbram-del_lines):
        line1 = f.readline() 
        lineoriginal = original.readline() 



        while k < bits_perline:
                if ((lineoriginal[k] == line1[k])):
                     a_write2 += " "
                else:
                     if (lineoriginal[k]=="0"): 
                     #if ((line1[k]=="0" and line1[k]=="1")):

                      num_bit_diff_flip_zero += 1
                     if (lineoriginal[k]=="1"): 
                     #if ((line1[k]=="0" and line1[k]=="1")):

                      num_bit_diff_flip_ones += 1

                     #if ((line1[k]==1 and line1[k]==0)):
                      #a_write_file2 = str(i+1) + " " + str(31-k) + "\n" + a_write_file2
                      #a_write2 += "^"
                      #num_bit_diff_flip_one += 1



                   # else:
                    #    a_write2 += " " 

                k+=1


                total_bit_flips=num_bit_diff_flip_zero+num_bit_diff_flip_ones
        i+=1

        k=0
i = 0
print files
print "Number of bits flip zero= %d" %num_bit_diff_flip_zero +"\n" +"Number of bits flip one= %d" %num_bit_diff_flip_ones +"\n" "Total bit flips = %d " %total_bit_flips


f.close()
original.close()
```

I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "random-ones-zeros.py", line 65, in <module>
    if ((lineoriginal[k] == line1[k])):
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I guess there is some issue with the reading the file automatically, instead giving name manually. But, didn't able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For this the string index is out of range because the value k is iterated once more than intended so the value of the variable exceeds the scope of the program. This should be able to be fixed by using substituting it to

if ((lineoriginal[k-1] == line1[k-1])):

Hope this helps, but I can't access Python right now so I can't test it out :-)

Comment: But this problem didnt comes when I give the file name. path = '*test1.rbd' it works. But I have 50 files I want to read it automatically instead giving name manually.